# Something like libgdx for C++ / cross-platform (with mobile) SDK

Tags: c++, libgdx

Is there an SDK like libgdx which allows me to code in C++? I really like the features libgdx has, but would prefer to code in C++.  I've looked around but can't find anything. I found the commerical Maramlade project, but that doesn't support Linux at all, plus I'd prefer an open solution.

Comment: if you are used to code in C++ i think that your best option is just to do your own engine.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid writing the cross-platform bits myself. I don't want a thick layer though, direct exposure to OpenGL ES is good, as is fairly low level sound access.  This is why libgdx sounds nice.

Comment: or you can just pick only the library that you are interested in, for the audio there is OpenSL ES http://www.khronos.org/opensles/ for example.

Comment: "Which tech to use" questions are off topic for the site: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/695/are-what-should-i-use-to-do-x-questions-really-on-topic-and-good

Comment: I'm not asking which to use, I'm asking which _exist_, which I find is a critical difference. It is very difficult to find this information with a web search. The answers are also factual, and not subject to opinion.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: That just makes it a poll question (list all the tech with properties X), which is likewise not acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer myself since I found something called [GamePlay](http://gameplay3d.org/). It appears to support the most platforms of any SDK I've seen so far and is all in C++. It doesn't quite have its Linux support yet working but it appears to be a priorty issue.

Comment: Their website has changed to http://www.gameplay3d.io/

Answer (score 1):

Guess you're looking for something more complete, but [gdx++](http://aevum.github.com/libgdx-cpp/) is the ongoing port of libGDX, though it still lacks some essential features - quoting from the [README](https://github.com/aevum/libgdx-cpp/blob/master/README.mdown#what-has-to-be-done):

- Backend polishing. Seriously, it's working, but there is a lot of stuff that is ugly and in a haste.
- iOS support
- GLES 2. Check if it's working
- etc *(whatever that entails)*

Porting efforts seem a little slow-paced at the moment though.

Comment: Okay, I see it now. It looks like it is still an active project, though isn't as complete as GamePlay.

Answer (score 1):

[Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki) is a cross-platform and open source framework. It allows to do everything which allows libgdx.

Comment: It looks like a 2d only library, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Someone over on badlogic forums was porting libgdx over to c++ a while back but I can't seem to find it now. Maybe you can politely ask over there? It may have been scrapped because the main branch will eventually support ios.

Comment: I see there was a project on github, but it's gone now.

Comment: I was actually talking about gdx++ that @junkdog mentioned but I think it's not being kept up to date.